# How to iterate a unique class in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have this list,

```
<ul id="list">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

And I want to dynamically add a class to it and will result to something like this,

```
<ul id="list">
  <li class="class-1">Item 1</li>
  <li class="class-2">Item 2</li>
  <li class="class-3">Item 3</li>
  <li class="class-4">Item 4</li>
  <li class="class-1">Item 5</li>
  <li class="class-2">Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

Here's my initial code,

```
jQuery(function(){
  var list = jQuery('#list').children('li');
  var arr = ['class-1','class-2','class-3','class-4'];
  jQuery.each(arr, function(index, el) {
    list.addClass(el);
  });
});
```

But all it did is to add all the classes on each list item. I guess I really don't know what I'm doing here. I'd really appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: perhaps you should iterate your list instead of your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please iterate over your list than array...
You can try this code

```js
jQuery(function(){
  var list = jQuery('#list').children('li');
  var arr = ['class-1','class-2','class-3','class-4'];

  list.each(function(index, el) {
      $(el).addClass(arr[index % arr.length]);
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
<li>Item 5</li>
<li>Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you this works. What I like about this solution is the fact that it doesn't matter how long my array of classes are and what class names I use.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with the use of `each`,

```
$('#list > li').each(function(i, elm) {
    $(this).addClass("class-" + ((i % 4) + 1));
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ut36pcxx/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`:nth-child()`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)** pseudo selector with an equation based on the array length and index and **[`jQuery.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)** or **[`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** array iterator

---

```js
jQuery(function() {
  var arr = ['class-1', 'class-2', 'class-3', 'class-4'],
    len = arr.length;
  jQuery.each(arr, function(i, v) {
    $('#list li:nth-child(' + len + 'n+' + (i + 1) + ')').addClass(v);
  })
})
```

```css
.class-1 {
  color: red
}
.class-2 {
  color: green
}
.class-3 {
  color: blue
}
.class-4 {
  color: yellow
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

---

**FYI :** **[How nth-child Works](https://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/)**

Comment: @user1448731 : glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating your list instead of your array.

Perhaps you can consider this:

```
jQuery(function(){
  var list = jQuery('#list').children('li');

  jQuery.each(list, function(index, el) {
    $(this).addClass('class-' + (index % 4));
  });

});
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the length of `list` is longer than `arr`.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for pointing that out. i was refactoring from his code

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jb4c0jup/)

```
  var list = jQuery('#list').children('li');
  var arr = ['class-1', 'class-2', 'class-3', 'class-4'];

  $('#list li').each(function(index, el) {
  console.log(index)
    $(this).addClass(arr[index % 4])
  });
```

You can iterate through the list and use the index with and get the `%4`

```js
  var list = jQuery('#list').children('li');
  var arr = ['class-1', 'class-2', 'class-3', 'class-4'];

  $('#list li').each(function(index, el) {
    console.log(index)
    $(this).addClass(arr[index % 4])
  });
```

```css
.class-1 {
  color: red
}
.class-2 {
  color: black
}
.class-3 {
  color: yellow
}
.class-4 {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This is similar to @Muhammad Usman's answer. The only diff is that you implied the "4" which in this case solves the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the answer of everyone I have arrived with this.

```
jQuery(function(){
    var list = jQuery('#list').children('li');

    var arr = [
        'class-1',
        'class-2',
        'class-3',
        'class-4'
    ];


    list.each(function(index, el) {
        jQuery(this).addClass(arr[index % arr.length]);
    });
});
```

Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.addClass` with a function that gets passed the index:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var classes = ['class-1','class-2','class-3','class-4'];
  $('#list > li').addClass(function(index) {
    return classes[index % classes.length];
  });
});
```

```css
.class-1 { color: red }
.class-2 { color: blue }
.class-3 { color: green }
.class-4 { color: yellow }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
</ul>
```